# Excel 2016 formula using only part of another drop down list cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to redesign an excel worksheet for my job. I have a cell (A20)  that needs to have the product of 2 cells (F3 and B20) in it and then have that cell (A20) colored blue and the cell (A20) gets locked to prevent data entry. I am running into 2 issues with this.

First, one of the cells (F3) that the formula gets a value from is a drop-down list that has 2 numbers for each option, but I only use the number on the left for the formula (the left number is 3 digits).

The second problem is that I am trying to make it so that the answer cell (A20) is left blank until BOTH F3 and B20 have a number in them. I did some research but I must be missing something since this does not work at all. This is the formula as it stands now (not working). I haven't even gotten to the coloring it blue and locking the cell once it returns the product (which I don't know how to do that either).

=IF(F3="" OR B20="","",F3*LEFT(B20,3))

I am not an excel expert and this is my first time using Superuser, so if I committed some cardinal sin in how I worded this question, I apologize. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OR syntax is `OR(crit1,crit2,...)`

so:

```
=IF(OR(F3="",B20=""),"",F3*LEFT(B20,3))
```

Comment: I both manually entered and copied and pasted that formula. The keeping it blank part does work, there is nothing displayed until I enter something in both B20 and F3, however, once I do put a number in both, I get a value error returned to A20 and it just shows ###### in the cell. I checked the formatting on all 3 cells and they are all formatted as number cells. For further clarification, here is an example. One of the 3 number options that they have in F3 is "120/208" written exactly as it is inside the quotation. I only need the 120 part of it for the formula. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use Evaluate, its on the formula tab, and step through the formula and make sure it is returning the value you think it is.

Comment: Ok, I Figured it out. I messed up when I gave the formula to you. I have B20 and F3 switched out in the multiplication equation. This is the corrected formula as it stands now (which does work). Thanks for all your help.                                                         =IF(OR(F3="",B20=""),"",B20*LEFT(F3,3))